# child maven project cannot find maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea

I use intellij2020.3.2, **maven version 3.6.3, java version 15.0.2**.
I has a **parent project** named **sdsd3**, and **child project** named **Module_Project**.
I **cannot package the child project**, here is the error message of parent and child project, respectively.

```
[INFO] SDSD3 Project ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.004 s]
[INFO] SDSD3 Project - Module ............................. FAILURE [  0.075 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.6.3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.6.3 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.6.3 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Here is my pom.xml of parent project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>aa.com.dennis</groupId>
  <artifactId>sdsd3</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>


  <name>SDSD3 Project</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <build.stage>local</build.stage>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.7.21</org.slf4j.version>
    <org.projectlombok.version>1.16.10</org.projectlombok.version>
    <org.springframework.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.apache.tiles.version>3.0.7</org.apache.tiles.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <mybatis.version>3.4.1</mybatis.version>
    <mybatis-spring.version>1.3.0</mybatis-spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <javax.servlet-api.version>4.0.0-b01</javax.servlet-api.version>
  </properties>
  <modules>

    <module>Module_Project</module>
  </modules>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

and pom.xml of child project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sdsd3</artifactId>
        <groupId>tw.com.gss</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>Module_Project</artifactId>


    <name>SDSD3 Project - Module</name>

<!--    <properties>-->
<!--        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>-->
<!--        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>-->
<!--    </properties>-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${mybatis-spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Module_Project</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${build.stage}</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/common</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

Why parent project can compile, but child cannot? How to fix it?
[image] here is my intellij maven setting

Comment: Do you get the same error if you package it from command line outside IDE?

Comment: I get same error if I package it from command line outside IDE(mvn clean package at parent project directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no compiler plugin in version 3.6.3. The recent version is 3.8.1.

The version of the compiler plugin is not related to the version of Maven itself.

The parent project does not use the compile plugin, so the problem appears when building the child.

Comment: When I comment build tag in parent pom.xml, `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Module_Project: Compilation failure`. How can I know which version is maven using?

Comment: I just check Maven3.6.3 was released at 2019-11-25. Maven Compiler Plugin was released at May, 2019. Do Maven3.6.3 use older version Maven Compiler Plugin when it is released?

Comment: I get lose. Because when I check `mvn -version`, it shows **Maven3.6.3**, **Java version15.0.2**, how can Java version15.0.2 use together with maven-compiler-plugin:3.1? And if the older version maven-compiler-plugin can work with new version Java, why does `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Module_Project: Compilation failure` happened?

Comment: The version of Maven and the version of the compiler plugin are not connected. Just always use the newest compiler plugin, in this case, 3.8.1.